# sum of square of each elements in the vector using for_each

Tags: c++, vector, stl-algorithm

As the function accepted by [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) take only one parameter (the element of the vector), I have to define a `static int sum = 0`  somewhere so that It can be accessed 
after calling the for_each . I think this is awkward. Any better way to do this (still use for_each) ?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int sum = 0;
void add_f(int i )
{
    sum += i * i;

}
void test_using_for_each()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    vector<int> a (arr ,arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    for_each( a.begin(),a.end(), add_f);
    cout << "sum of the square of the element is  " << sum << endl;
}
```

In Ruby, We can do it this way:

```
sum = 0
[1,2,3,4].each { |i| sum += i*i}   #local variable can be used in the callback function
puts sum    #=> 30
```

**Would you please show more examples how `for_each` is typically used in practical programming (not just print out each element)?** Is it possible use `for_each` simulate 'programming pattern' like map and inject in Ruby (or map /fold in Haskell).

```
#map in ruby 
>> [1,2,3,4].map  {|i| i*i} 
=> [1, 4, 9, 16]

#inject in ruby 
[1, 4, 9, 16].inject(0)  {|aac ,i| aac +=i}  #=> 30
```

EDIT: Thank you all. I have learned so much from your replies. We have so many ways to do the same single thing in C++ , which makes it a little bit difficult to learn. But it's interesting :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

// functor for getting sum of previous result and square of current element
template<typename T>
struct square
{
    T operator()(const T& Left, const T& Right) const
    {   
        return (Left + Right*Right);
    }
};

void main()
{
    std::vector <int> v1;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(4);

    int x = std::accumulate( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0, square<int>() );
    // 0 stands here for initial value to which each element is in turn combined with
    // for our case must be 0.
}
```

You could emulate std::accumulate as in [nice GMan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326118/sum-of-square-of-each-elements-in-the-vector-using-foreach/1326145#1326145), but I believe that using std::accumulate will make your code more readable, because it was designed for such purposes. You could find more standard algorithms [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: I don't think vector iterators are guaranteed to be in the std namespace. If that's correct then ADL is not guaranteed to work here, and the questioner has not specified a compiler.

Comment: You're right. I've just checked - standard doesn't guarantee that iterator is a part of std namespace. Only reverse iterators are part of `std` namespace.

Comment: onebyone: Wow, good catch. I checked the standard and you're absolutely right. So e.g. if vector<T>::iterator was typedefed to T*, ADL would indeed fail. -1ing to get the OP's attention... (The post is otherwise excellent BTW.)

Comment: OK that was fast, no need to -1 after all! :)

Answer (score 51):

No, don't use std::accumulate() use std::inner_product(). No functor required.

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

void main()
{
    std::vector <int> v1;
    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);
    v1.push_back(4);

    int x = std::inner_product( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v1.begin(), 0 );
}
```

Comment: Very elegant...exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Why this isn't the top answer?

Answer (score 7):

`for_each` returns (a copy of) the functor that it was using. So, something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class square_accumulate
{
public:
    square_accumulate(void) :
      _sum(0)
      {
      }

      const T& result(void) const
      {
          return _sum;
      }

      void operator()(const T& val)
      {
          _sum += val * val;
      }

private:
    T _sum;
};

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> a (arr ,arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    int sum = std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), square_accumulate<int>()).result();

    std::cout << "sum of the square of the element is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

As demonstrated by other answers, though, [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/) is the best way to go.

Comment: This is a good sample of std::accumulate emulation. Useful for teaching purposes.

Comment: Down vote comment? Can't improve if I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `for_each()` for this, use `accumulate()` from the `<numeric>` header:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct accum_sum_of_squares {
    // x contains the sum-of-squares so far, y is the next value.
    int operator()(int x, int y) const {
        return x + y * y;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a[] = { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    int ssq = accumulate(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof a[0], 0, accum_sum_of_squares());
    cout << ssq << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The default behaviour of `accumulate()` is to sum elements, but you can provide your own function or functor as we do here, and the operation it performs need not be associative -- the 2nd argument is always the next element to be operated on.  This operation is sometimes called `reduce` in other languages.

You could use a plain function instead of the `accum_sum_of_squares` functor, or for even more genericity, you could make `accum_sum_of_squares` a class template that accepts any numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

As a general solution to such issue with STL: instead of passing a function, you can pass a `functor` -- for example, an instance of any class implementing `operator()`. This is much better than relying on global variables, since said instance can keep and update its own state!  You could think of it as a kind of "compile time duck typing": generic programming does not constrain you to pass a "function" in that place, anything that "behaves like a function" (i.e., has a proper `operator()`) will do as well!-)

Answer (score 3):

`std::for_each` is for doing something with *each* element.  If you want get a result from a calculation on *all* the elements, there's `std::accumulate`.  If you are wanting Haskell's `map` behaviour, use `std::transform`.

You can abuse either of these three to do the same thing as any of the others, since ultimately they are just iterating over an iterator (except for `transform`'s form that takes two iterators as input.)  The point is that `for_each` is not a replacement for map/fold - that should be done by transform/accumulate - although C++ doesn't natively have something that expresses the map/fold concept as well as Haskell does - but both gcc and VC++ support OpenMP which has a much better analogue in `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Inject in Ruby is a much closer match to calling `for_each` with a full-fledged functor, like [GMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326118/sum-of-square-of-each-elements-in-the-vector-using-foreach/1326145#1326145) explained above.  Lambda functions with variable capture in C++0X will make the behaviour between the two languages even more similar:

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    std::vector<int> a (arr ,arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    int sum = 0;
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](int i) { sum += i*i;} );

    std::cout << "sum of the square of the element is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```